# How to package and update a nodejs application for freebsd?

Tags: node.js, express, freebsd, packaging

I have a simple express web server and I want to know how to package this app as a single executable file (something like .WAR for java applications) so I can install it on a FreeBSD without installing NodeJS or `npm install`.

There are some solutions like npm pkg module but setting freebsd as a target gives error in windows, and in freebsd, the pkg is a command and I couldn't use it.

And how can I update this app with rollback and etc? Should I have an API for uploading new version and writing shell scripts for this? If yes, what are the best commands for such cases?

There might be a simple solution for these questions but since I am new to both NodeJS and FreeBSD, I don't know where to begin.

Comment: Single file installs are not a usual pattern you see with node - this is probably a recommendation type question and posdibly off-topic. Additionally FreeBSD is not a common target these days so that will definitely make your experience with node starting out more difficult. Have you considered a more mainstream target OS?

Comment: Unfortunately, for this app, the only option I have is freebsd. (I used pkg and it worked fine for windows and linux and there are many other solutions).

Comment: Can you just make it a port and not a package? That can just be tarred and installed with a simple `make`.

Comment: Thank you. I am starting to read about this and see what are the differences.

Answer (score 0):

#1. First install the pkg command of node

> **doas npm i pkg -g ** OR  ** sudo npm i pkg -g**

#2. You can execute commands using absolute paths

> **/usr/local/bin/pkg -h**

#3. This will not conflict with system commands

Comment: Thank you. Now, I can use `pkg` in my freebsd. :-D